# Will Season 10 still be canon after the X-Files television miniseries?

Tags: canon, the-x-files, x-files-tv-miniseries, x-files-season-10-comic

*The X-Files: Season 10* is a comic book continuation of *The X-Files* television series and films that (apparently) picks up from where the film *I Want to Believe* leaves off.   The first issue was released by IDW Publishing in June 2013.  *X-Files* creator Chris Carter is the executive producer of the comic book and it is considered [canon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_X-Files_Season_10).

**Question:**

Now that the Fox Network and Chris Carter have announced the creation of a six-episode *X-Files* television miniseries (to begin airing in January 2016), will *Season 10* still be canon?  If *Season 10* is still canon, then how will the miniseries and *Season 10* be related to one another in terms of in-universe chronology?

Comment: It's going to be confusing now - I've seen a lot of articles referring to the TV miniseries as "Season 10".

Comment: @pacoverflow : Indeed, which I think further supports the answer below &mdash; this "Season 10" is overwriting the comic book one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## No, *Season 10* will not be canon.

I have been aware for some time of an *XFN* (*X-Files News*) interview with Chris Carter from March 2015 in which he commented on *Season 10* in regards to the miniseries.  [Wikipedia](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_X-Files_(miniseries)#Writing) cited this interview in a vague way, saying

> Carter also revealed that the miniseries' plot has no connection to the *Season 10* comic book series...

This wording is ambiguous.  It might mean that *Season 10* is no longer canon, or it might mean that *Season 10* is still canon but the miniseries will not overlap with any of its plot lines.

Until recently, any links I found to the original *XFN* article (including the one at Wikipedia) were broken, and searching on Google and the *XFN* site directly did not produce the interview.

However, a Reddit post I found today contained a working link:

- [XFN Exclusive: Chris Carter on #XFNRevival](http://www.xfilesnews.com/news/latest-news/91-xfn-exclusive-chris-carter-on-xfilesrevival)

The wording in the actual article is less ambiguous:

> Carter also clarifies that while he thinks that IDW's *The X-Files: Season 10* plot lines are very interesting, they won't be used in the revival of the TV show.

I interpret this as saying that Carter is distancing himself from those plot lines and revoking the canon status he previously granted to the comic series.

Comment: Based on what you quoted (clicking the XFN Exclusive link results in a server error), it could still mean that Season 10 is canon but the miniseries won't overlap any of its plot lines.